# Smallest distance in a list to the number 0 supplies amount of that number with map

Tags: dictionary, haskell

I want to create a function absmin which gets a list of floating point numbers and returns the amount of that number which has the smallest distance to 0.
We should do it with the function map. My first idea was that the function abs mentioned the problem with amount, but know my question is, how it is possible to create the point with the smallest distance to 0 and that with the map function, can somebody help me?

```
absmin :: [Double] -> Int
absmin [] = []
absmin (x:xs) = abs (map (x:xs))
```

Okay, now i changed to:

```
absmin xs = map abs xs
```

But with the specification: `absmin :: [Double] -> Double` it didn't work, maybe i´m to stupid, but i try and try and it didn't work

Comment: Adding examples of input and expected output would improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list like `[3.14, 2.98, -0.1]` and need to find which number is closest to zero, you need to first map `abs` to that list, and then you need to find the min.

Now `min` has signature `Ord a => a -> a -> a` so it only considers two numbers at the same time. Fortunately we can use a fold to fold this function over our list.

```
Prelude> absmin = foldr1 min . map abs
Prelude> absmin [3.14, 2.98, -0.1]
0.1
```

The problem with this is that we don't know if the closest number to zero was `0.1` or `-0.1`.

So let's map each element to a tuple containing its absolute value *and* the original value. We can define a `minBy` function that lets us find the minimum of two values based on a function like `fst`.

After we've folded this function over the list of tuples, we just need to call `snd` on the result to get the original value.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| minBy f a b
Prelude|   | f a <= f b = a
Prelude|   | otherwise  = b
Prelude| :}
Prelude> absmin' = snd . foldr1 (minBy fst) . map (\x -> (abs x, x))
Prelude> absmin' [3.14, 2.98, -0.1, 0.1]
-0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min()` and `abs()` functions to find the smallest absolute value in a list of numbers, and then use `map()` to apply this value to each element in the list.

Comment: Okay, so I must say map (min.abs) (x:xs)

Comment: Be careful. `()` actually does mean something in Haskell, and `min()` for instance, does not work. You should remove the parens when naming functions.